# Round Robin Records in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to round-robin names into a "TASK" column depending on which type of job is assigned in the "JOB" column.  My table looks like this for example:

[image: example table]

my code is as follows:

```
Sub macro2()

Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset
Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("table1")

Dim employee(2) As String

employee(0) = "empname1"
employee(1) = "empname2"

Dim i As Integer
With Rst
    i = 0
    Rst.MoveFirst

    Do While Not .EOF
        If Rst.Fields("JOB") = "LETTER" Then
            Rst.Edit
            Rst.Fields("Task").value = employee(i)
            Rst.Update
        End If
        .MoveNext
        i = i + 1
        If i > 2 Then i = 0
    Loop
End With

DoCmd.Requery
End Sub
```

The problem is, sometimes it "misses" an assignment, and I am not sure why.

[image: table pic did not pull]

It should have kept looping those 2 names into the column, but it wont.  However, sometimes after running it a couple of times it will do it. Upon opening the DB fresh, it will not, and will appear as above after completing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of the code allows `i` to have a value of 2.

```
i = i + 1
If i > 2 Then i = 0
```

But `UBound(employee)` is 1, which means `employee(i)` should throw a *"subscript out of range"* error when `i` is 2.  But you didn't report getting that error, so I don't understand what's going on.

Also your first screenshot shows "Letter" and "Change" in the *Job* column, but the second screenshot shows all as "Letter".  That's another puzzler.

Maybe you need to load the recordset with a query rather than the full table.

```
Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Job, Task FROM table1 " & _
    "WHERE Job = 'Letter'")
```

Then as you move through the recordset rows, toggle `i` between 0 and 1.

```
i = IIf(i = 1, 0, 1)
```

It looks to me like those changes might allow your code to work as you intend.  However consider an approach which is more flexible and easier to maintain.  Store the employee names in a table and open a second recordset, *rsEmployees*, to hold those employee names.  As you move through the first recordset, *Rst*, also advance the second: `rsEmployees.MoveNext`  If you reach `rsEmployees.EOF`, do `rsEmployees.MoveFirst`  That should "round robin" the assignments.

That approach would allow you to add/remove employees from the available pool by simply updating the employees table.  You wouldn't need to revise your VBA code each time you add/remove employees.

Comment: Sorry about the screen shot differences, I was attempting to see what happens when I make all 4 tasks the same name. This problem occurs whether 2, 3, or 4, tasks are assigned and that was what I was testing.  My idea is to create a form that allows the person running the macro to select checkboxes of who is available to be assigned, then to redim the array to fit the size based on who is checked, then assign them out.  Different employees do different things however, so I need to differentiate and pull from who does what and whether or not they are present.

Comment: OK, I had a hunch this thing would be more complicated than the question.  ;-) So, you have an array of some undetermined number (but likely greater than 2) of employee names.  Increment `i` *after* you assign a name to *Task*, but if `i = UBound(employee) + 1`, make `i` zero instead.  That still leaves the issue of how you gather up the names to load into the array, but we'll assume you have that piece worked out already.

Comment: thanks for your idea, I am going to try and create a second recordset as suggested, with a checkbox indicator to whether they should be imported and assigned or skipped along with the job name's that those people handle.  Thanks for the above example as well, I am going to play around with a bit and see what I come up with

Comment: That can work if the employees table includes a Yes/No field, but could be challenging in a multi-user application.

Comment: basically, one user is using access to import, sort data, and generate a list of those tasks.  But right now they have to manually assign it, referring to a spreadsheet as to who does what.